# Can Javascript PptxGenJS library show preview before save?

Tags: pptxgenjs

I am using PptxGenJS library to create a pptx files with javascript. I want to preview of pptx before saving. How can I handle it?

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid this is not possible. you need to get the created slides somehow into PowerPoint in order to view it, which requires a save and a load.

To really create a preview capability for slides, you would have to write a full slide rendering engine in JavaScript, which is obviously a huge effort.

Maybe your script can save files somewhere in a temporary place, and create simple macro in PowerPoint which enables some sort of preview, after which files can be saved with their final name and file path?

Comment: It will be very simple and basic question. But I want to ask. How can I download it into server and show it? How can I Download it into server or anywhere else? Can you prefer any technique?

Comment: @Alperen I can answer the question whether PptxGenJS can show previews (the answer is no unfortunately), I am less qualified about suggesting alternative solutions. Sorry.